# How can I change this Nokogiri code so that it returns HTML and not the content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have this HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note><div><strong>this is note 2</strong>. it has a url.</div></en-note>
```

I want to extract this from it:

```
<div><strong>this is note 2</strong>. it has a url.</div>
```

At the moment, I am doing this:

```
html_doc.xpath('//en-note').each do |a_tag|
    p a_tag.content
end
```

Which gets me this:

```
"this is note 2. it has a url."
```

How can I change the code so that the actual HTML is returned, not just the text?

Comment: Did you ever try `puts a_tag` instead of `p a_tag`? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `to_s`

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > Nokogiri::HTML('<tag>content</tag>').xpath('//tag').first.content
 => "content" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > Nokogiri::HTML('<tag>content</tag>').xpath('//tag').to_s
 => "<tag>content</tag>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
html_doc.at_xpath('//en-note').to_xml
```